# Does `export default` Prevent Us From Using Named Parameters?

Tags: ecmascript-6, parameters

```
export default {
    fetchService({ url, reqBody }) {
    console.log(url, reqBody);
  }
};

import fetchService from "@/services/FetchService";

const results = fetchService({
      url: "hello",
      reqBody: "hello222"
    });
```

*TypeError: Object(...) is not a function*

So, to be clear, I am exporting from 1 file and then importing into other files in the same app.

However, if I do this *without* `export` - that is, I just include the `function()` definition/expression in the same file each time manually, then it works as expected.

I also tried `export function`.

It will only work if I just have a 'normal' `function()` definition in the same file. So...what's the deal? Why can't I use this [named parameters technique](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html#_simulating-named-parameters-in-javascript) with `export default`?

I expect it to work something like this:

```
function dest({url = "something", someting}) {
    console.log(url, someting);
}

dest({someting: "good!"});
```

*something good!* [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta594mdf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: use `export default function fetchService(){}` instead

Notice that TypeError: `Object is not a function`. That sounds to me like you're attempting to invoke an Object instead of a function, which means that the thing that you're attempting to `import` is an Object.

Given the `export` statement you have above, this error makes sense! Taking `fetchService` out of the equation entirely, what would you expect to be `export`-ed if you wrote `export default {}`? I would expect an empty Object to be `export`-ed, hence the error.

> I also tried export function

Close! That would have given you a single `export` that could have been `import`-ed through destructuring syntax, e.g. `import { fetchService } from '@/services/FetchService'`.

You can use `export default function` instead to get the result that you're looking for, here, which would be `import fetchService from '@/services/FetchService'`

Comment: Actually, after seeing first comment from question, I figured it out and got it working. Thanks for the additional context on this!